# Not recognized command when running Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, msbuild, dockerfile

whenever I run docker build I'm getting:

> 'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   and 
>   'nuget.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

However, when I run msbuild or nuget restore from CMD it works fine on it's own. I've already added paths to System Variables / Path

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `msbuild` is not available in `microsoft/dotnet-framework-build` image.

I suspect (!) that this image contains the `dotnet` binary but not `msbuild`. One alternative is to find an image that includes it. Another option is to add it to the `microsoft/dotnet-framework-build`.

You are able to access `msbuild` from your local machine because it's installed there. When you run `docker build`, the `Dockerfile` is executed within the operating system defined by the image's `FROM` statements.

HTH!

Comment: correct. I changed it to: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build-env (in docker file)